# Link for Google I'm Feeling Lucky search Results

Tags: google-search

I am forwarding to Google search results. By using `https://www.google.com/#q="whatiwanttosearchfor"` you can do a Google search. Is there a way to automatically go to the first result?

Answer (score 3):

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&btnI
```

This should be your URL, with %s replaced with your search term.